# Can I do anything with very rare items?

Tags: rocket-league

I have a few "Very rare" quality items in my inventory that I don't really use anymore. I know I can't trade them in for anything as "very rare" is the highest quality you can get, but I'm wondering if there's anything I can do with these spare items.

Answer (score 3):

The upcoming [rumble update](http://www.rocketleaguegame.com/news/2016/09/rumble-update/) adds Player-to-Player Trading, so you could try and trade them for items you want.

Comment: I read somewhere that trading does not work for Xbox players, but I can't find the source